# Randomly failing polymer web component test

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, systemjs, es6-module-loader

Yet another attempt to marry Polymer with ES6 classes.

And it almost works except a wct test failing randomly on a polymer component with an imported es6 class (by systemjs). As far as I understand, this happens because the script, containing class definition, gets loaded after mocha executed the test.  The polymer component consists of two parts - html and javascript (to compile latter to es5),

html:

```
<dom-module id="my-test">
   <template>hello</template>
   <script>
      System.import('elements/my-test.js');
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

javascript:

```
import {User} from 'elements/model/user.js';

Polymer({
 is: "my-test",

 method: function(){
   console.log("method, user="+this.val);
 },

 ready: function(){
   this.user= new User(); //this.user is randomly undefined
 }
});
```

This seems to work quite stable in the browser, at least when loaded from localhost. But the only thing which ‘fixes’ the test is delaying Polymer’s ready call:

```
Polymer.whenReady = function (f) {
   console.log("polymer ready");
   setTimeout(f, 100);// "fix"
   //f();
}
```

which means at some point all this will fail in browser too (maybe when serving not from the localhost).

I’m thinking about getting somehow to the system-register’s promises and making something similar to HTMLImports.whenDocumentReady, but I still don’t have clear understanding of how all this works.

So any ideas and suggestions are highly appreciated!

The sample app is on github:

```
git clone https://github.com/bushuyev/test_test.git
cd test_test
git checkout tags/random_fail
npm install
bower install
gulp wct
```

To make it succeed more often than fail - change verbose to true in wct.conf.js.

kind of update: [How to import system js SFX library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882316/how-to-import-system-js-sfx-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use Polymer, SystemJS and TypeScript (like ES6 but with added Polymer-friendly syntax) together in a very nice way, also handling HTML imports using SystemJS. That does involve a timing issue, and I've published a [small shim](https://github.com/charto/charto-polymer-shim) that first waits from webcomponents.js to load and catches its ready event (before other code gets a chance to see it), then it loads Polymer and finally all other components and TypeScript code. Then it dispatches the event again so Polymer finishes initializing itself.

Here's [an article about combining the technologies](http://blog.charto.net/typescript/Taming-Polymer-with-SystemJS-and-TypeScript-part-1/) with the mentioned solution, downloadable code and a demo.