# Polymer Compute Binding after a script has loaded

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I am creating a Polymer web component that leverages moment.js. I create a computed binding that takes in a date and returns a string formatted by moment.js. Problem is, sometimes this method is run before the app loads the moment.js library resulting in a variable undefined error. Is there a way I can wait to return a value to the view or delay when the computing function gets called?

Please see below for code example:

```
<span>{{computedDate(date)}}</span>
<script>
    Polymer({
        ...
        computedDate: function(date) {
            return moment(date, "MM-DD-YYYY").fromNow()
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be is similar to mine and there is even solution proposed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32254689/656449 . Although I haven't yet tried it but they guy look wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be certain moment.js is loaded you could load it dynamically & wait for the load event to fire:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = path/to/moment.js;
script.onload = function () {
  //here you know moment.js is loaded, so set the loaded "flag" to true
};

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Then in your computed binding watch for changes to the loaded flag, only using moment when it's true:

```
<span>{{computedDate(date, loaded)}}</span>
```

Comment: This would then cause the script to be added every time this web component is added to the DOM no?

Comment: That would depend on how you use it. For example you could wrap the dynamic script loading with an if statement that checks if the "moment" object is already available & if so don't re-add it's script tag.